# Mounting Intel Raid ISM in RAID 1 on dual booting Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, mount, raid

I have a machine with a two HDDs configured in Windows 10 for RAID 1, which I would like to mount from Ubuntu 20.04.

I can see the drives with `lsblk`

```
~$ lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
loop0                          7:0    0   9.1M  1 loop   /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
loop1                          7:1    0  96.6M  1 loop   /snap/core/9804
loop2                          7:2    0  29.9M  1 loop   /snap/snapd/8790
loop3                          7:3    0  62.1M  1 loop   /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop4                          7:4    0  49.8M  1 loop   /snap/snap-store/467
loop5                          7:5    0  29.9M  1 loop   /snap/snapd/8542
loop6                          7:6    0 255.6M  1 loop   /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop7                          7:7    0  55.3M  1 loop   /snap/core18/1885
loop8                          7:8    0   2.2M  1 loop   /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
sda                            8:0    0   3.7T  0 disk   
└─isw_ecghdfaggh_Volume0     253:0    0   1.7T  0 dmraid 
  ├─isw_ecghdfaggh_Volume0p1 253:1    0   260M  0 part   
  └─isw_ecghdfaggh_Volume0p2 253:2    0    16M  0 part   
sdb                            8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk   
└─isw_ecghdfaggh_Volume0     253:0    0   1.7T  0 dmraid 
  ├─isw_ecghdfaggh_Volume0p1 253:1    0   260M  0 part   
  └─isw_ecghdfaggh_Volume0p2 253:2    0    16M  0 part   
sr0                           11:0    1  1024M  0 rom    
nvme0n1                      259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk   
├─nvme0n1p1                  259:1    0   600M  0 part   
├─nvme0n1p2                  259:2    0   512M  0 part   /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p3                  259:3    0   128M  0 part   
├─nvme0n1p4                  259:4    0 171.1G  0 part   
├─nvme0n1p5                  259:5    0    28G  0 part   /
├─nvme0n1p6                  259:6    0  59.6G  0 part   [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p7                  259:7    0   694G  0 part   /home
```

They are the drives named sda and sdb.

`dmraid` claims the RAID is already active.

```
~$ sudo dmraid -ay
RAID set "isw_ecghdfaggh_Volume0" already active
```

But it is apparently not mounted. If I try to mount it, I get an error:

```
~$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/isw_ecghdfaggh_Volume0 /media/Data/
mount: /media/Data: /dev/mapper/isw_ecghdfaggh_Volume0 already mounted or mount point busy.
```

I can't find the UUID of the drive either:

```
~$ sudo blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p6: UUID="c35ec8d6-80b7-4bb3-ac58-9ccc809d16fb" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="275c9c53-9c57-4ce5-b930-32de7dc90e38"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="9fdf9d51-2097-4e8a-8501-f4610814298e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b1c9cac5-e6bc-40c8-84eb-a2fe7a672818"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="Windows RE Tools" UUID="DEFE58EDFE58C007" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="61787626-5405-4c40-b9c3-2bb9f8994677"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="3A5A-C39D" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="51005fd5-0b5e-4378-8f7b-f43121df3391"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: TYPE="BitLocker" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="76c0c0e7-05b2-49d0-900e-82aa378dc33a"
/dev/nvme0n1p7: UUID="bce2e697-df65-4a1d-9187-d9bf153b588c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3df059fe-01d4-4a50-b8fb-31ba260e0e82"
/dev/sda: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/sdb: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/mapper/isw_ecghdfaggh_Volume0p1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="A843-B42E" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="5417e899-32d3-418a-93bc-ebfc7cb4ee5b"
/dev/mapper/isw_ecghdfaggh_Volume0: PTTYPE="PMBR"
```

Can you help me mount the drive, or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. `sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda /dev/sdb` gave me the UUID of the raid. I edited that into `/etc/fstab` and rebooted Ubuntu.

Now the RAID is mounted and I can share files between the two OS'es.